# jquery draggable into sortable strips id

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I have a list of standard text items from a 'library' that users can drag into a sortable list so they can build (and modify) their own document. Both lists are created from an Ajax call. Note that I have created the receiving list before the donor one and it is all wrapped in a $(document).on change function

After checking numerous posts here I have the drag and drop working but the process is stripping out the id of the dragged element. That, of course breaks the serialize and update processes.

I am using JQuery 1.10.2 and JQueryUI 1.10.3 where connectWith seems to have been replaced by connectToSortable

Here's a complete example (also on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dy2Ft/8/):

EDIT: I have changed the id in the first list to call it 'ref' and added a stop event to grab the ref value (which it does because I tested it with an alert) and then attempted to add the id with a value of ref to the item but it does the update on the original rather than the clone. So I am still stuck but a bit further forward. At least there will be no duplicate IDs

HTML:

```
<select id='confiss'>
    <option value='1'>Document One</option>
    <option value='2'>Document Two</option>
</select><br />    
<ul id="libry">
<li ref="listItem_1" class="phlis ui-draggable" >
<img class="handle" width="16" height="16" src="http://s17.postimg.org/7mb9zwkuz/arrow.png" alt="move">
  This is the first test phrase
</li>
<li ref="listItem_2" class="phlis ui-draggable">
<img class="handle" width="16" height="16" src="http://s17.postimg.org/7mb9zwkuz/arrow.png" alt="move">
  This is the second phrase
</li>
    <li ref="listItem_3" class="phlis ui-draggable" ><img class="handle" width="16" height="16" src="http://s17.postimg.org/7mb9zwkuz/arrow.png" alt="move">This is the third phrase</li>
</ul>
    <div>The target list is below me</div><br />
<ul id="contphrss" class="ui-sortable sort-list"><li id="listItem_0" class="phlis ui-draggable" ><img class="handle" width="16" height="16" src="http://s17.postimg.org/7mb9zwkuz/arrow.png" alt="move">This is a false placeholder</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.sort-list li {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

.sort-list li img.handle {
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: move; 
}
.phlis{display: block;
    padding: 3px 3px; margin-top: 3px;
    background-color: #FFAAFF;}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#contphrss').sortable({
    handle: '.handle',
    update: function () {
        var order = $('#contphrss').sortable('serialize');
        var contr = "&cont=" + $('#confiss option:selected').val();

    }
});
$('.phlis').draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    opacity: 0.45,
stop: function(event,ui){
var newid =$(this).attr('ref');
$(this).attr('id',newid );
},
    connectToSortable: '#contphrss'
});
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I expect it's related to your using `helper: 'clone'`, which is asking jQuery UI to clone an element with an `id`. Doing so would create an invalid DOM, so presumably jQuery UI removes the `id` from the clone, and things go south from there. If you can create a [minimal, complete self-contained example](http://sscce.org) and post it to the question (and *optionally* also to http://jsbin.com, http://jsfiddle.net, or similar), it may help people help you.

Comment: The use of helper: 'clone' is explicitly stated in the api documentation [link](api.jqueryus.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable)[/link] and I also thought it would break the DOM so I have tried leaving helper to the default 'original' and used handle: '.handle' for dragging, but then the item will not go into the target list.

Comment: Of course 'clone' is documented. The point is that you're cloning elements **with `id`s**. Again, put a **complete** self-contained example in the question, and people may be able to help.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use edit delete or flag on the question as my Avast antivirus disables them, putting up an annoying green box to say the site is safe. It is useful elsewhere so I don't want to remove the plugin. I have done it as [link] http://jsfiddle.net/Dy2Ft/8/

Comment: @ Emulite: Being able to edit your question is essential to using Stack Overflow. If you can't edit your question, you'll have to ask for help elsewhere.

Comment: @ Emulite: In that fiddle, it *copies* the elements into the second list, it doesn't move them. Of course the `id` can't be retained.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I have disabled the Avast plugin so I can also now access the functions.

Comment: @Emulite in your example case it does not make much sense to the keep the id when cloning an element.  Because Id's should be unique to each element.  That is why your dragged element is not retaining its `ID`, It will however retain `classes` and `data`.  It could be done but ID's are meant to be unique.

Comment: @Trevor I appreciate that.  However the ID (which contains the reference to the item) is essential for serialize and I am looking for an alternative way to work around it by dragging the original list item but the code is stuck with the constraints of connectToSortable or nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want the ID to stay with the clone here is one way to do it.

```
var id = '';
$('#contphrss').sortable({
    handle : '.handle', 
    update : function (event, ui) { 
        ui.item.attr('id',id);   
        var order = $('#contphrss').sortable('serialize');
        var contr="&cont="+$('#confiss option:selected').val();

    },
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        id = ui.sender.attr('id');    
    }
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Dy2Ft/10/

**Update**

EDIT by emulite To protect the integrity of the DOM I have used the attribute 'ref' to pass the value as per the modified HTML above and modified the answer to pick that up. This makes it work beautifully

`id = ui.sender.attr('ref');`

Comment: I did not alter Trevor's jsfiddle so refer to the answer for guidance